# Can the length of the URL affect the layout?

Tags: css, url, layout

This is really a weird problem. So we have an existing navigation that goes like this:

```
<div class="tab"> 
    <a href="URL1/file.php" target="_top">HOME</a>
    <a href="URL2/file.php" class="active" target="_top">NAV2</a>
    <a href="URL3/file.php" target="_top">NAV3</a>
    <a href="URL4/file.php" target="_top">NAV4</a> 
    <a href="URL5/file.php" target="_top">NAV5</a>
</div>
```

Thing is once we change the URLs to something longer (cause the web address of the live site is longer than the test site), the layout of the header goes awry (the items should be in one horizontal line but when we make the URLs longer, some of the text goes to the next line).

Why is that so? I mean it's not the text on the URL, it's the URL itself which shouldn't affect how things are displayed.

Has anybody encountered this weird problem? Happens on all browsers.

Comment: Could you post your css? This sounds ridiculous to me, `<a href=""` values don't affect layout in any way. Unless you have a closing `"` inside the url which messes up the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds impossible. The only two ways I can see this happening are:

- you've got some javascript which manipulates the DOM depending on the value of those href=""
- you've got [css content](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/) property outputing some content based on the value of those href=""

Is it any of those two?

Also, have you tried validating the html source using http://validator.w3.org/?

Comment: I already fixed, I just removed target="_top" from each a tags. Seems really weird that it will affect the layout. Anyway, this is just a quick fix as we're going to revamp the site soon. The CSS is kinda confusing and the site is a bit messy. There may be some scripting that does affect it but now we don't have time to dig through.

Comment: Can you at least run the site (with target="_top" on) without JavaScript and let us know whether it still breaks? It will be useful for concluding the question.